# Load products into custom theme home in magento 2.0.1?

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, magento-2.0

I have created a custom theme which extends to a blank theme. After setting custom theme I have lost my product on home page only. What I want to do load product into the content area of the custom theme. I am trying to override templates but no effect. At the same time, I feel difficult to finding appropriate layouts to override like (cms_page_view.xml for home page), developer tool display only templates and Blocks not layouts.

Theme Path:/app/design/frontend/ChennaiBox/Style/theme.xml

**I want to load product into below green box like luma theme home page**

[image: load product into green box]

Please post any code snippet to regarding this or just provide hints to what are the steps to achieve this.

Appreciate for any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can achieve this by widget

Login to admin

1. CONTENT -> Pages -> Home Page -> edit

in content tab

2. In editor click second icon (insert widget or insert frontend app) now one pop up window open select type is catalog product list.
3. save page

now the widget get visible in home page

my page look like this

[image: this]

(My additional work: remove add cart button and only show image when click image it will navigate to product detail page) so don't get confuse may be your look and feel will be different

**Reference:**

https://mage2.pro/t/topic/26

https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento2/display-products

Comment: How do you achieve it programmatically ?

Answer (score 1):

About finding the appropriate layouts, please see our official docs:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html#debug-theme-layout

Plz let us know if it's helpful.

Comment: thanks for the reply, each module layout folder contains more xml file suppose phtml file name not found in all xml then we search in fallback scheme, This will take so much time to customize for single change. Am I right?